# Got two circles and a point. How to get get circle along it

Tags: javascript, math

I got a mathematical problem for designing icons, and I am looking for a JavaScript solution.

I take 2 circles, each a different radius and position, and a point. I want to know the smallest circle that contains the two circles and goes along the point.

[image]

*The red cirle is the circle I want to know*

In want a function like this:

```
function calculate(c1x, c1y, c1r, c2x, c2y, c2r, px, py){
    //Calculation
    return {
        x: outX,
        y: outY,
        r: outR
    };
}
```

Comment: A nice question which offers the priceless chance to use `Math.hypot()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of degenerate cases: one circle is inside another and so on.

For the most general case - big circle touches both small ones and goes through the point - we need to solve a system of three equations for three unknowns `cx, cy, R`:

```
(px - cx)^2 + (py - cy)^2 = R^2
(cx1 - cx)^2 + (cy1 - cy)^2 = (R-r1)^2
(cx2 - cx)^2 + (cy2 - cy)^2 = (R-r2)^2
```

You can try to solve it with paper and pencil or use some program for symbolic calculations like Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, MathCad etc.

P.S. to slightly simplify calculations, subtract point coordinates from all values, solve system

```
cx^2 + cy^2 = R^2
(cx1' - cx)^2 + (cy1' - cy)^2 = (R-r1)^2
(cx2' - cx)^2 + (cy2' - cy)^2 = (R-r2)^2
```

and add px, py to the result

Answer (score 1):

```
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1-y2, 2));
}

function calculate(c1x, c1y, c1r, c2x, c2y, c2r, px, py){
    var dpc1 = distance(c1x, c1y, px, py) + c1r;
    var dpc2 = distance(c2x, c2y, px, py) + c2r;
    var dc1c2 = distance(c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y);
    var theta = Math.acos((dpc1*dpc1 + dpc2*dpc2 - dc1c2*dc1c2)/(2*dpc1*dpc2))/2;
    var outR = Math.max(dpc1, dpc2);
    var outX = px + outR * Math.cos(theta);
    var outY = py + outR * Math.sin(theta);
    return {
        x: outX,
        y: outY,
        r: outR
    };
}
```

Comment: according to my fiddle, that does not work, as it doesn't go through the point? https://jsfiddle.net/arneg6u7/

Comment: Could you add some sort of explanation and the principles used.

Comment: It doesn't actually work.  I don't have time to work on it anymore, so I'll retract my answer if you want.